# Page freezes on logout - AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, angularfire

Every time I try and log off, the page freezes and I can't go to another page before i hit refresh. I'm using Angular and Firebase firestore and theirs authentication function.

**EDIT:**
I've added my app-routing.module.ts for more information and hopefully will clarify what the problem exactly is.

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  authState: any = null; // Used to hold the users data

  // calls the AngularFireAuth to get info about user credentials
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, public fireService: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth => {
      this.authState = auth;
    }));
  }

  // is called when company register. creates firebase auth login with email and password
  // this also creates a document with the information from the registration in the collection companies
  registerWithEmail(email: string, password: string, companyUser: CompanyUserInterface) {
    return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((data) => {
      this.authState = data;
      // Gets user id and added to company for unique id
      companyUser.UID = data.user.uid;
      return this.fireService.collection('companies').add(Object.assign({}, companyUser));
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    });
  }

  // is called in login and checks if login info is correct in firebase
  loginWithEmail(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((data) => {
      this.authState = data;
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      });
  }

  // TODO: is bugged. if time look into. (has to refresh page on logout to be able to move)
  logout(): void {
    this.afAuth.signOut().then();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']).then();
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './views/home/home.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './views/about/about.component';
import {PagenotfoundComponent} from './views/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import {ContactComponent} from './views/contact/contact.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './views/login/login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './views/register/register.component';
import {UserinfoComponent} from './views/userinfo/userinfo.component';
import {BoardComponent} from './views/board/board.component';
import {ScheduleComponent} from './views/schedule/schedule.component';
import {TermComponent} from './views/term/term.component';
import {AngularFireAuthGuard} from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  // free for all visitor
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'terms', component: TermComponent},
  // has to be logged in to access these paths
  {path: 'userinfo', component: UserinfoComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'board', component: BoardComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'schedule', component: ScheduleComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard]},
  // other
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}, // redirect to `first-component`
  {path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent},  // Wildcard route for a 404 page
];

// configures NgModule imports and exports
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor your `logout()` function like this:

```
  logout(): void {
    this.afAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
  }
```

Essentially, instead of calling two async functions one right after another, this would chain them.

Comment: It still freezes on the login page and I've tried rerouting it to a different page also

Comment: I've added more information. hopefully that helps